# Isabelle `subst` but replace right side with left side

Tags: isabelle

Suppose the goal is `P l`, then I can use `apply(subst X)` where `X` is of the form `l=r`
and as a result I obtain `P r`. Now my question is whether there exists some other tactic like `subst` but which could use `X` to change `P r` into `P l`.

Here is an example

```
theorem mul_1_I : "(x::nat) = 1 * x" by (rule sym, rule Nat.nat_mult_1)

theorem "(λ x::nat . x) ≤ (λ x::nat . 2*x)"
  using [[simp_trace]]
  apply(rule le_funI)
  apply(subst mul_1_I)
  apply(rule mult_le_mono1)
  apply(simp)
  done
```

where

```
lemma nat_mult_1: "1 * n = n"
```

Right now I have to first prove this auxiliary lemma `mul_1_I`  which applies `sym` to  `nat_mult_1` and only then I can use `subst`. Would be ideal if I didn't have to create new lemma specifically for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `symmetric` attribute to derive the swapped fact. For example, if `x` is of the form `l = r`, then `x [symmetric]` is the fact `r = l` (which is also valid due to the symmetry of `=`). Therefore, in your particular case you can use `subst nat_mult_1 [symmetric]` directly and avoid creating your auxiliary lemma.